# Show all colleagues on the company page

Tags: support, status-completed, developer-story

Me and my colleagues are trying to use the same company in our developer stories, so that when someone clicks on that company, all of us show up on the company page. Currently, there are two company pages for the same company. How could we merge them?

Comment: Please consider rolling back your question to revision 2.

Comment: But the links were not working anymore. Users will change names and companies they're working for. The exact links are not important for the solution, which is just manual merging by the stackoverflow team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [merged the two company lists](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/370309/pace-telematics-gmbh?storyType=1), so now you should show up with your coworker!

Comment: Thank you! What if there is another coworker? How do companies get merged automatically?

Comment: If another coworker goes to their developer story and adds a position, they should see your company in the autocomplete dropdown. If your coworker does not select your company from the dropdown, a new company list could be created if a unique company name, url, and image combination is provided. Currently the merge process is not automatic.

Comment: The question "How could we merge them?" was not answered. @jisooshin How did you merge these two lists? Rather how does one merge lists?